# POST Form to MongoDB in EJS using Express (Node.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, express

I've been searching the internet for a long time now and I've yet not managed to find any useful information on this problem.

**Use case**:

POST Data to mongo database using EJS and Mongoose.

This is a simple registration for users in a Modal View.

---

This is my Registration Form:

**Top.ejs**

```
<form id="register-form" action="/" method="POST" style="display:none" enctype="multipart/form-data">                
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div id="div-register-msg">
                <div id="icon-register-msg" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></div>
                  <span id="text-register-msg">Register</span>
                </div>
                  <input name="firstname" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Firstname" required>
                  <input name="lastname" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Lastname" required>
                  <input name="email" class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="Email" required>
                  <input name="phonenumber" class="form-control" type="number" placeholder="Phonenumber" required>
                  <input name="password" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Password" required>
                  <input name="password_c" class="form-control" type="password" placeholder="Confirm" required>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
              <!--<div class"checkbox">
                <label><input type="checkbox">I have read and understood the terms for Debate.It</label>
              </div>-->
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Register">
            </div>
          </form>
```

Below you'll see the POST Route. Please be aware that this is working with **POSTMAN**. The data is posted into a mongoLab online database. Working like a charm.

```
router.post('/', jsonParser, function (req, res){
mongoose.connect(url, function(err, db) {
    console.log(req.body);
    console.log("User created!");
    var user = {
        firstname : req.body.firstname,
        lastname : req.body.lastname,
        email : req.body.email,
        phonenumber : req.body.phonenumber,
        password : req.body.password
    };

    UserReq.create(user, function(err, data) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(400);
        }
        else {                
            res.status(201);
            //res.send(data);
            res.json(data);
            mongoose.disconnect();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

I do not believe there is anything particular wrong with the route, but might be the EJS Page.

---

Here you'll see my Modal View. The Form's are in a single file, but they have been separated into their own forms and given an ID.

[image]

Alright, so when I click the "Register"-button I do not get any action at all. I've tried with some JQuery, but I don't get any action.

I hope anyone in here can help me out. Maybe give me a tip and some theory behind.

If you've any misunderstandings in my explaining, please do hesitate to tell me. I will correct it or try to be more clear. This is written just 5 minutes before the guests for Christmas arrives.

Have a wonderful Christmas everyone. May you all have a wonderful night.